# Spectra of Dirac operators

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, operator-theory, differential-operators

**1.** Suppose that $M$ is a spin manifold. The spin structure of $M$ is not uniquely defined: in other words, $M$ may have many
nonequivalent spin structures. For each choice of spin structure there is uniquely defined Dirac operator: it is obtained as
$c \circ \nabla$ where $\nabla$ is a spin connection on spinor bundle-we have uniqueness if we require our Dirac operator to
commute with the *charge conjugation* operator $J$. However to different spin structures we get different Dirac operators.

> Suppose that $D_1$ and $D_2$ are two Dirac operators for two different spin structures. How are the spectra of $D_1$ and $D_2$
>   related (if there is any relation)?

**2.** Suppose now that $M$ is spin$^c$ manifold (not necessary spin)-this is weaker condition. In such circumstances one can 
still define spinor bundle (i.e. such bundle that the Clifford action is irreducible) and a spin connection. One can therefore
also define Dirac operator in this context, however it is no longer uniquely determined (we don't impose condition for commutation
with charge conjugation operator since simply there is no such operator in this context).

> Let us choose spin$^c$ structure on $M$ and let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be two Dirac operators defined for this spin$^c$ structure. 
>   How are the spectra of $D_1$ and $D_2$ related?

**3.** Finally let us assume that $D$ is some *Dirac type* operator (i.e. operator of the form $c \circ \nabla$ where $c$ is Clifford
action and $\nabla$ is Clifford connection-we don't assume that the Clifford action is irreducible) and suppose that we *twist* $D$ by
some vector bundle $E$ to obtain $D_E$ (by twisting we mean forming the operator $c \circ \nabla^{S,E}$ where $\nabla^{S,E}$ is the 
connection on tensor product $S \otimes E$ where some connection on $\nabla^E$ on $E$ is chosen and $c$ acts only on $S$-part of $S \otimes E$).

> > How are the spectra of $D$ and $D_E$ related?

Comment: You probably assume $M$ to be a Riemannian manifold in addition? Without a Riemannian metric, the Dirac operator is not unique after fixing the spin structure. I am currently not aware of papers treating the whole spectra. But I know about some eigenvalue estimates: for Q1, Bernd Ammann and Christian Bär studied surfaces in [Math. Z. 240 (2002), 423–449](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s002090100392). For Q3, Vafa and Witten proposed an eigenvalues estimate in [Comm. Math. Phys. 95 (1984), 257–276](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103941573).

Comment: Yes, we fix Riemanian metric, consider Levi-Civita connection with respect to this metric and then form the Dirac operator. Anyway, it could be equally interesting to ask what could happen with the spectrum of Dirac operator if we change Riemannian metric (for example the asymptotics remain the same and is encoded in the dimension of manifold).